# How could I align/resize 5 rectangles on maximize in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

So here's the deal... I have a normal (not maximized - custom size) form and 5 columns and 2 rows of tiles (TRectangle) on it (FIG. 1). My question is how could I use Anchors, or Layers or anything to properly align/resize the tiles on maximize (FIG. 3). Meaning if by my logic I set all Align properties (L/T/R/B) to True, the tiles should just get slightly bigger and keep the same margins between them (FIG. 3), but actually, the don't, they just overlap each other when maximized, like in FIG. 2. My question is how could I set the tiles so they are just slightly bigger and keep the same margins between them like when the form is normal (my custom size) when the window is maximized - basically have them fill the form nicely, not overlapping. Thanks!
PS: Sorry for my lame paint drawing :)
[image: Mockup]

Comment: Not exactly what you asked (the distance between the rectangles will change proportionally) is to select all rectangles, reset any settings you might have done and only set `Align = Scale`. This will set also the `Anchors = [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom]`

Comment: Thanks man, except for the top margin/position (which changes), the size now scales accordingly and the distance between rectangles remains the same. So far I'm using your solution. A fix for the top margin/position would be good, but I can work with this :D

Answer (score 2):

After some consideration I thought that there should be a solution that does exactly what you asked for. So, in addition to the `Align=Scale` property, the solution involves using the `Margin` property for all external sides and, by one of two adjacent components, for the internal sides.

If we consider the rectangles, in the following form, numbered from left to right and from top downward, the margins are set to the value of 5.0, as follows:

```
Top row:
 1: left, top, right
 2..5: top, right
Bottom row:
 6: left, top, right, bottom
 7..10: top, right, bottom
```

The result can be seen in the original sized form and in the form resized by two horizontally and vertically. The distances to the form borders and between the rectangle stay constant, and this holds true also for a fully maximized form.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for a **TGridPanelLayout**. They are a bit fiddly to use, but can prove themselves in size change situations.

1. Create a **TGridPanelLayout** and set its Align = Client.
2. **Add the missing columns**. When you first create it, the layout has 2 rows and 2 columns. You can get more by adding items to the layout's ColumnCollection.
3. **Set all the columns' properties** to SizeStyle = Percent and Value = 20.
4. **Add 10 TRectangle to the layout** and set their Align = Client
5. **Set the layout's Padding and Margin properties** to obtain the gaps you want around between and around the rectangles.

All this does not use scaling, so margins will not change with resizing. It just redistributes the extra space within the rectangles.

*A note on point 3. Setting multiple columns' or rows' Value property when the SizeStyle is Percent... can be fiddly with the IDE. You have to do it many times... each time the Value gets closer to what you requested. As of Berlin this has not been fixed (I don't have Tokyo). If you don't want to do that, you can edit the dfm directly and just write the value ;)*